# не работает счастливый билет

Tags: python

Если выводить по отдельности каждый элемент на print, то все показывает. А так не работает.

```
a,b,c,d,e,f = input()
if (a+b+c)==(d+e+f):
  print("Счастливый")
else:
  print("Обычный")
```

Comment: напечатайте `print(a+b+c)` чтобы понять в чем ошибка

Comment: круто! Спасибо за оперативность!

Answer (score 1):

`input()` возвращает строку, поэтому распаковывая ее по переменным, тоже получите строки в переменных и сложение будет конкатенацией строк

Как вариант, приведите значения из `input()` в числа:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f = map(int, input())
```

Суть: `input()` вернет строку, строка это итерируемый объект, который возвращает по одному элементу (символу). Функция `map` применяет функцию `int` к каждому элементу. В итоге, при распаковке в переменные попадут числа для каждой цифры

Comment: заработало, но я не понял что сделал) но все равно спасибо.

Comment: @VANjKE, добавил описание в ответ :)

Comment: Да не, я про то что "map" не знаю что такое) и почму после "int" запятая а не скобки. Я пока бревно, не бум бум.

Comment: @VANjKE, просто `int` - `callable`, т.к. это встроенная функция (хотя точнее это класс), а `map` вызовет его, т.е. это тоже самое, что: `= (int(x) for x in input())`

Answer (score 0):

Добавил к ответу [gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red) строчку кода

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = map(int, input())
print('Счастливый') if (a + b + c) == (d + e + f) else print("Обычный")
```